# Opens the map with a certain position of the camera

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to java, I installed Google maps in my application, but when you open the card, open a very large scale of the map, a function I need to use for that would map opened at a certain city? And just a second question - please tell me what the name of the function is responsible for determining the location the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is rather vague but the API documentation should be able to help you here.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker

Just pick out which API you need. It should be something like setLocation(Coordinates) in all of them.